# Use scikit-learn to pick out abnormal load profiles

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am looking for how I can use scikit-learn to help me with a business problem.

I work for an electricity utility and we have to pick out the peak loads at substations. However, we are only interested in peak loads when the network is in a normal state. Currently we do this by plotting 3d surface graphs (with the x=date, y=time of day, z=load) and manually inspecting the load shape. "Spikey" loads - or peak loads that appear after a step change are caused by switching in the network rather than customer demand - and we must ignore these "false peak loads". The attached graphic gives an example - as you can see - it is usually fairly obvious. 
[image: 3d Load Profile Example]

I have started to use scikit-learn (kaggle - titanic etc) - and I feel that it should be possible to use machine learning to filter out these "false peak loads" - but I have no idea where to start or which algorithm is best suited to this problem.

The data is fairly simple

```
    Date         0:00           0:15           0:30 ...etc etc
6/08/2013        54.4273        57.0923        53.7607... 
7/08/2013        54.413         52.7667        51.24... 
8/08/2013        51.3207        53.264         53.2603... 
9/08/2013        57.8673        59.5287        55.921... 
10/08/2013       62.92          61.4653        60.2743... 
11/08/2013       55.1523        55.8627        52.219...
```

Any pointers or examples gratefully received

Comment: You could take first derivative of load over time, then convert it into a binary classification task and use any supervised learning algorithm.

Comment: I think you should ask this on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/
Also look here, maybe useful for you: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#outlier-detection